# Building generic method for List<Enum>

Tags: c#, enums

In my application, I have something like:

```
public enum Locations {
  LocationA,
  LocationB,
  LocationC
}

private List<Locations> _myLocations;

public Int64 PackedLocations {
  get {
    return PackEnumList(this._myLocations);
  }
}
```

So: an enum (backed by int), a List of those enum values, and a read-only property which returns the result of a method I've left out so far.

That method, PackEnumList, is meant to give me a 64-bit integer where each BIT denotes whether the corresponding enum value was selected or not in a list of unique enum values. So in my example above, if _myLocations has only one item: {Locations.LocationA}, the result would be 1 (binary: ...00001), if we then add Locations.LocationC to that list, the result would be 5 (binary: ...000101). The implementation isn't important right now (but I'll include it below for completion/interest/feedback), but the signature of that method is:

```
public Int64 PackEnumList(List<Enum> listOfEnumValues) {
   ...
}
```

**When I compile, I get an error that "the best overloaded method ... has some invalid arguments".**

I'm guessing this is because _myLocations is being seen as a List of int values, but I'd like PackEnumList() to work even if the enumeration being used were backed by something else, if possible.

Is there a more appropriate way to make a method which will accept a List/Collection of any enumeration?

For completeness, here's the rest of what I'm trying to do (these are static because they're in a shared utility class). These are completely untested yet (since I can't get past the compile error when calling the pack method), so take them with a grain of salt. And there might be a better way to do this, I'm doing this half to solve an interesting problem, and half because I think it is an interesting problem.

```
    public static Int64 PackEnumList(List<Enum> listOfEnumValues) {
        BitArray bits = new BitArray(64, defaultValue: false);
        foreach (var value in listOfEnumValues) {
            // get integer value of each Enum in the List:
            int val = Convert.ToInt32(value);
            if (val >= 64) {
                // this enum has more options than we have bits, so cannot pack
                throw new Exception("Enum value out of range for packing: " + val.ToString());
            }
            bits[val] = true;
        }
        var res = new Int64[1];
        bits.CopyTo(res, 0);
        return res[0];
    }

    // (this method is a little farther from the ideal: the resulting list will need
    //     to be matched by the caller to the appropriate List of Enums by casting 
    //     each Int32 value to the Enum object in the list)
    public static List<Int32> UnpackEnumList(Int64 packedValue) {
        string binaryString = Convert.ToString(packedValue, 2);
        List<Int32> res = new List<Int32>();
        for (int pos = 0; pos < binaryString.Length; pos++) {
            if (binaryString[binaryString.Length - pos - 1] == '1') {
                // bit is on
                res.Add(pos);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Be careful... `Enum` is a boxing conversion

Comment: [Flags] on the Enum ended up being a far better solution for the overall process. Thanks to Jon Skeet and Wayne!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a more appropriate way to make a method which will accept a List/Collection of any enumeration?

Within straight C#? Nope. But you *can* fudge it...

I have a project called [Unconstrained Melody](http://unconstrained-melody.googlecode.com) which allows you to make a generic method with a constraint of "T must be an enum type" or "T must be a delegate type". These are valid constraints at the IL level, but can't be expressed in C#

Basically Unconstrained Melody consists of two parts:

- A library of useful methods with those constraints, where the source code is written using *valid* C# which doesn't actually represent those constraints, but uses a marker interface
- An IL-rewriting project (ugly but servicable) which converts those constraints into the real "unspeakable" ones

(The expectation is that users of the library would *just* use the rewritten binary.)

It sounds like you *could* use the latter part of the project for your code here. It won't be terribly pleasant, but it would work. You might also find the library part useful.

As a side thought, you might want to consider using a `[Flags]`-style enum instead:

```
[Flags]
public enum Locations {
  LocationA = 1 << 0,
  LocationB = 1 << 1,
  LocationC = 1 << 2
}
```

Comment: [Flags] is new to me, I'll look into that first. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Change your method signature to `public Int64 PackEnumList(IEnumerable<Enum> listOfEnumValues)`

And then call it like following:

```
public Int64 PackedLocations 
{
    get { return PackEnumList(this._myLocations.Cast<Enum>()); }
}
```

Comment: That will still fail as covariance doesn't work for value types (and `Locations` is a value type).

Comment: Now you've still got it boxing everything, which is unfortunate. But at least it'll compile...

Answer (score 1):

A `List<Enum>` is not a `List<Locations>` nor a `List<Int32>`. Use a generic method to handle the list:

```
    public static void PackEnumList<T>(IEnumerable<T> list) where T : IConvertible
    {
        foreach (var value in list)
            int numeric = value.ToInt32();
        // etc.
    }
```

Comment: That constraint isn't valid C# - see my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize it was not. However, why not simply leave out the constraint? Obviously it is not perfect, but it meets the condition of accepting any enum type. The only problem is that it accepts more than enum types.

Comment: But now it doesn't really answer the question of "Is there a more appropriate way to make a method which will accept a List/Collection of any enumeration?"

Comment: I don't think that is the question. I think the question is how to get  it to work at all. Just going based on that is the part of the question that is **bold**...

Comment: Well it's a question within the original post, and you're not addressing it. Yes, you've addressed *one part* of the question...

Comment: The **bold** was really meant to help the TLDR folks. This looks like a workable last-resort solution if I can't get anything cleaner working in a reasonable time, so it does add value here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd change your signature method to:

```
public Int64 PackEnumList<T>(IEnumerable<T> listOfEnumValues) where T : struct, IFormattable, IConvertible {
...
}
```

The where T : struct... constrains it to enum types only (any any other struct implementing both interfaces, which is probably very low)

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise that, it's just how it's done in my workplace